# How to order a table that came from Google Sheet if a column is type "number" but Power Apps interpret it as "text"

Tags: powerapps

In Power Apps,

A view created with a Google Sheet data source, the numbers are interpreted as text, and a view with an "Id" column (number) is ordered but due to it being considered text, then the order is like 1, 10, 11...  when the order must be 1,2,3,...

1. Create a connection with Google Sheets
2. Create a phoneview and a BrowseGallery is added, Modify like next:

SortByColumns(Search([@Transacciones], TextSearchBox1.Text,"Descripción","Cuenta_x0020_Destino","Cuenta_x0020_origen"),
"Id", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))

3. The view is ordered but "Id" column is interpreted as text, but in the Sheet is a number. So the order is is 1, 10, 11...  when the order must be 1,2,3,... (see image)
   [view ordered but the Id is considered text but is number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6I7w.png)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve changed for this:

```
Sort(Search([@Transacciones], TextSearchBox1.Text,"Descripción","Cuenta_x0020_Destino","Cuenta_x0020_origen"),
     Value(Id), If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

I mean, change `SortByColumns` by "Sort", this is because `SortByColum` requires a column name and Sort requires a formula that is evaluated for each row.